Possibility of BMM in less than $n^{\omega}$?
Obviously, we can reduce Boolean Matrix Multiplication to classic MM (if the result is at least $1$, we consider it as "true" or $1$), which yields an algorithm for BMM in $n^{\omega}$. My question is: Is there an algorithm that can solve BMM even faster? Or, more likely, is there a hardness result showing this is unlikely/impossible?

Well, what about the following BMM to MM reduction: consider the boolean matrix as $1$ and $0$. Multiply by any classical MM algorithm. If $c_{i,j}\geq 1$, set it to $1$ (equivalently: $true$).

My bad, I was talking about combinatorial BMM. If you use a classical (algebraic) algorithm, it should of course work.

There is no known algorithm, and no known barrier to this. I'm also of the belief that, ultimately, BMM should have a faster algorithm than standard MM.
I don't know if I have a lot of strong reasons why I believe this, other than intuition. Maybe one data point is the fact that in the cell-probe model, one can do Boolean matrix vector multiplication much faster than n^2 probes, but this is not known for matrix vector multiplication over a small field. For a reference, see e.g. Larsen and Williams SODA 2017.
